# Nginx (reverse proxy) and Angular (with SSR & i18n) - Use correct localized app based on the lang cookie value

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx

I have an Angular 11 application with two locales at the moment which I serve them at:

```
http://localhost:4000/en
http://localhost:4000/fr
```

I need a nginx configuration which will check if the user has set a lang cookie with value as one one of the two languages (en or fr).
If lang cookie is set the appropriate localized app should be used, otherwise it should default to en. Added example nginx config for modification.
Is this possible with nginx or should be done on express level.

```
server {

    listen 80;

    root /var/www;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name site.com www.site.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/en;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Assuming your language cookie name is `lang`, you can try the following configuration:

```
map $cookie_lang $backend {
    fr      127.0.0.1:4000/fr;
    default 127.0.0.1:4000/en;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$backend$request_uri;
        ...
    }
}
```

I added the `$request_uri` to the `proxy_pass` directive argument because according to nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be determined:
>
> ...
>
> - When variables are used in proxy_pass:
>
>   ```
>   location /name/ {
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1$request_uri;
>   }
>   ```

and our backend definition includes an URI part (`/en` or `/fr`).